# Filter bad keyboardWillShow notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

So I've got a bit of a weird issue. When a user continues on to a new screen in my app without dismissing the keyboard, then goes back to the previous screen, locks their phone and then unlocks it, I get sent a `keyboardWillShow` notification.

When they return to the original screen I don't receive a `keyboardWillShow` notification, and when they continue on to the new screen I receive a `keyboardDidHide` notification, indicating that the system knows the keyboard is hidden. If they manually dismiss the keyboard and then follow the steps above, I won't get the `keyboardWillShowNotification` when I unlock the phone.

The main issue is that I hide the toolbar in the `didHide` notifications and un-hide it in the `willShow` notifications. So when I turn the screen back on and get the `willShow` notification, the toolbar shows at the bottom of the screen with no keyboard. I've tried calling `endEditing` on the `textField` in `viewWillDissappear` just as I do in the callback for hitting done on the toolbar, but that still causes it to show.

So, is there any way to filter out `keyboardWillShowNotifications`, or is there any root cause for why I'm getting a `keyboardWillShowNotification` when I lock and unlock my phone after the original steps?

Edit: I also receive a call to `keyboardDidShow`, even though there is no keyboard visible on screen.

Edit 2: Using the userInfo dictionary provided in the notifications, I've found something interesting:

When I get a `keyboardDidShow` notification and the keyboard is showing, it has a frame of (0, 308; 320, 260) as it's ending frame. When it does not actually show the keyboard, it has a frame of (0, 524, 320, 44), which appears to be the same frame as the toolbar. I may be able to use these frames to differentiate between good and bad notifications.

Comment: "endEditing on the textField" or it's applied to view?

Comment: I've called it on the textField, and there's a call to resignFirstResponder on the toolbar.

Comment: You might want to have a try with the more common `[self.view endEditing:YES]`

Comment: Good suggestion, unfortunately I'm still receiving all of the notifications for the keyboard showing if I don't manually dismiss it by hitting done.

Comment: Any other text controls on screen? You may want to put a debug point in textField will start edit after unlock to check who's calling it.

Comment: Shoot, another good suggestion, again unfortunately there's no calls made to textFieldShouldBeginEditing before the keyboardDidShow notification is sent out. I've also only got the one textField on this screen.